# How to set up React native with android studio?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, android-emulator

I am very new to react native and mobile dev. I am trying to set up react native to work on my android studio emulator and when I do it does not load up the phone emulator as it is supposed to. When it did load up the phone emulator and I pressed a to open my project o Andriod doesn't open up but gave me this error.

Couldn't adb reverse: adb.exe: error: device offline[image]

Comment: Does the emulated device start?

Comment: Does the emulator start on android studio?

Comment: yes the emulator starts on andriod studio